# Save Firepath ( Firebug plugin ) result

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug, firepath

i m using [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/), a firebug extension for Firefox browser.

How to show/save the result, example: want to grab all link in pages.

there will be list of links in firepath window.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Andy,

I have tried to do the same thing you are doing and I couldn't find a way to do this with Firepath.

However I did find a tool in Chrome [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl/details) that allows you to copy your results. This did the trick for me, hope it works for you and everyone else.

Cheers,
Devin

Answer (score 0):

Seems You want feature, not implemented by intention of particular plugin (Firepath finds HTML elements matching chosen CSS selector(s) or XPath expression - but You want more - to render filtered HTML page, not just to see filtered CSS or HTML source) but You always can ask for that developers.

Althou there is workaround possibilty - share them with a friend via the FriendlyFire feature. [Below is a demo video of using Firefinder and the FriendlyFire feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTRptjiAZv8#t=93)